# extern without type

Tags: c, extern

If the syntax of `extern` is

```
extern <type> <name>;
```

how do I `extern` if I have an unnamed, single use struct:

```
struct {
    char **plymouthThemes;
    char *plymouthTheme;
} global;
```

I've tried

```
extern global;
```

without any type, and it doesn't work.

Or, do I have to name the struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to name your struct and put it in a .h file or included the definition by hand in every source file that uses global. Like this

```
///glob.h
    struct GlobalStruct
    {
       ///char** ...
       ///
    };

///glob.cpp
   #include "glob.h"
   struct GlobalStruct global; 

///someOtherFile.cpp
#include "glob.h"

extern struct GlobalStruct global;
```

Comment: Do I have to do this in every file that I want to use `global` in?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you. If you want use global from many places and just declare them, I am afraid you will have to name your struct

Comment: Now I have the problem that other files don't know what a `struct globalStruct` "is" when I do `extern struct globalStruct global;`.

Comment: Of course, you have to include the definition of GlobalStruct... let me edit my answer

Comment: Thanks. My skills working with structs and multiple files in C is quite weak.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to name a struct there's common method:

```
--- global.h: (file with global struct definition):

#ifdef GLOBAL_HERE /* some macro, which defined in one file only*/
#define GLOBAL
#else
#define GLOBAL extern
#endif

GLOBAL struct {
    char **plymouthThemes;
    char *plymouthTheme;
} global;

---- file1.c (file where you want to have global allocated)

#define GLOBAL_HERE
#include "global.h"

---- file2.c (any oher file referencing to global)

#include "global.h"
```

The macro GLOBAL is conditionally defined so its usage will prepend a definition with "extern" everywhere except source where GLOBAL_HERE is defined. When you define GLOBAL_HERE then variable gets non-extern, so it will be allocated in output object of this source.

There's also short trick definition (which set in single .c file where you allocate globals):

```
#define extern
```

which cause preprocessor to remove extern (replace with empty string). But do not do it: redefining standard keywords is *bad*.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you need to declare only one but still need to define the variable in each other file that uses it. The definition includes both the type (in your case a header define structure - which therefore need include) and the `extern` keyword to let know the compiler the declaration is in a different file.

here is my example

ext.h

```
struct mystruct{
    int s,r;
};
```

ext1.c

```
#include "ext.h"

struct mystruct aaaa;

main(){
    return 0;
}
```

ext2.c

```
#include "ext.h"

extern struct mystruct aaaa;

void foo(){
    aaaa;
}
```

ext3.c

```
#include "ext.h"

extern struct mystruct aaaa;

void foo2(){
    aaaa;
}
```